# I am getting an error ORA-00922: missing or invalid option 00922. 00000 - "missing or invalid option" . It is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the maintenance history for the bus Ch-20 including the date and location of the maintenance, wether or not the maintenance session was scheduled or not, the full name and phone number of supervising staff

It is not working at all in the oracle sql database

```
CREATE TABLE Maintenance (

MaintenanceID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
DateOfMaintenance DATE NOT NULL,
Description CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Rego VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
StaffID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT Maintenance_PK PRIMARY Key (MaintenanceID),
CONSTRAINT Maintenance_Rego_FK FOREIGN Key (Rego) REFERENCES Bus(Rego),
CONSTRAINT Maintenance_StaffID_FK FOREIGN Key (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff(StaffID)

);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Staff (

StaffID NUMBER(5) , 
FirstName VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL, 
ContactNumber VARCHAR2(10),
JobPosition VARCHAR2(25),
CONSTRAINT Staff_PK PRIMARY Key (StaffID)

);
```

```
CREATE VIEW ViewE AS 
SELECT 
    DateOfMaintenance AS Maintenance_Date,
    Description AS Maintenance_Location,
    MaintenanceID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN MaintenanceID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Scheduled'
        ELSE 'Not Scheduled'
    END AS Maintenance_Scheduled,
    FirstName || ' ' || LastName AS Supervisor_Name,
    PhoneNumber AS Supervisor_Phone
FROM 
    Maintenance m
INNER JOIN 
    Staff s ON s.StaffID = m.StaffID
WHERE 
    Rego = 'CH-20';
```

How do we solve this?

I received an error that says Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 2):

Table `bus` is missing, but you're referencing it from `maintenance`; this is a *dummy* table, just to make later code work:

```
SQL> create table bus (rego varchar2(10) primary key);

Table created.
```

`staff` goes before `maintenance` because it is also being referenced:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Staff (
  2  StaffID NUMBER(5) ,
  3  FirstName VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
  4  LastName VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
  5  ContactNumber VARCHAR2(10),
  6  JobPosition VARCHAR2(25),
  7  CONSTRAINT Staff_PK PRIMARY Key (StaffID)
  8  );

Table created.
```

The last table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Maintenance (
  2  MaintenanceID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  3  DateOfMaintenance DATE NOT NULL,
  4  Description CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  5  Rego VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  6  StaffID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  7  CONSTRAINT Maintenance_PK PRIMARY Key (MaintenanceID),
  8  CONSTRAINT Maintenance_Rego_FK FOREIGN Key (Rego) REFERENCES Bus(Rego),
  9  CONSTRAINT Maintenance_StaffID_FK FOREIGN Key (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff(StaffID)
 10  );

Table created.
```

View uses `phonenumber` column, but it doesn't exist; I used `contanctnumber` instead:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ViewE AS
  2  SELECT
  3      DateOfMaintenance AS Maintenance_Date,
  4      Description AS Maintenance_Location,
  5      MaintenanceID,
  6      CASE
  7          WHEN MaintenanceID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Scheduled'
  8          ELSE 'Not Scheduled'
  9      END AS Maintenance_Scheduled,
 10      FirstName || ' ' || LastName AS Supervisor_Name,
 11      contactnumber AS Supervisor_Phone
 12  FROM
 13      Maintenance m
 14  INNER JOIN
 15      Staff s ON s.StaffID = m.StaffID
 16  WHERE
 17      Rego = 'CH-20';

View created.

SQL>
```

Everything seems to be OK.

A side note: this is a SQL*Plus demo; it works in SQL Developer as well.